# verb describing "stomach's singing"

Tags: word-request

What's the correct verb to describe the action of a hungry person's stomach making some noise?

For example:

I hadn't had breakfast and lunch, so this meeting was a huge embarrassment for me as my stomach was constantly _________________ to everyone's amusement, but I couldn't do anything about it.

Comment: Just FYI, in most of the US (at least among groups other than perhaps adolescent males and drunks) one's stomach growling would not be cause for everyone's delight.  Most people would politely ignore it.

Comment: @jamesqf - Thanks. I wonder if the word "delight" is the right one here. My original choice of words was "to everyone's fun" and what I meant by it was that everyone around was giggling, but later my question was edited and "fun" was changed to "delight". Using the word "delight" strikes me more like implying that people really enjoyed the sound of growling coming from my stomach, rather than found that funny.

Comment: The technical term is “*borborygmi*”, but it’s not commonly used in casual English.

Comment: @jamesqf I can certainly be privately amused while being outwardly professional. If I knew the person well, I would probably tease them goodnaturedly after the meeting. If the meeting was very casual and everyone knew each other well, I might mention it as it happened too! If I didn't know the person well I'd ignore it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The word/verb you are looking for is *growl.* [Your stomach *growls*](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-does-your-stomach-gro/) when you are hungry.

> I hadn't had breakfast and lunch, so this meeting was a huge embarrassment for me as my stomach was constantly ***growling*** to everyone's amusement, but I couldn't do anything about it.

---

Added note: The question is concerned about a colloquial and everyday language; hence, *growl* is my choice. *Rumbling* is specific to the stomach's character and may be used in [*examining* a person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stomach_rumble). Typically, **on a lighter note**, when you are hungry, *stomach growling* suits better.

Comment: I've never heard this usage.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica It doesn't matter whether you've personally heard it or not. There's an American user who states this is the _only_ way they've ever heard it. That is irrelevant too. The word is correct, however, this answer implies its the only correct word when there are many alternatives.

Comment: @CJDennis You'll find plenty of people on this site adding their own experience on whether they've heard a phrase or not. But I'm sorry to have offended you and will ensure not to bother you with my irrelevant, immaterial comments in the future.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica My intent is not to offend. A single data point, no matter who it comes from, is irrelevant. It's only when we collect thousands of data points that meaningful patterns can be discerned. What value does it provide to anyone how _I_ say a thing? What right do I have to hold myself up as especially typical?

Comment: @CJDennis This doesn't seem like a particularly useful comment thread

Answer (score 41):

In normal English you would use "[Stomach rumble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stomach_rumble)", though "growl" is also possible. You can also use "rumble" as a verb and say "my stomach is rumbling".

There seems to be some difference in dialect (common for such things), and "rumble" is more common in British English, whereas "growl" is more American.  Also "rumble" is a more friendly sounding word, and would be more common when talking to children, but "growl" would be more appropriate for writing for adults.

There are a couple of medical terms (peristaltic sound, borborygmus) but only doctors will understand those, so don't use them (even though the second is an excellent word to say).

Comment: Yes, we should start using the second one.

Comment: Can I say, "My stomach was rumbling"?

Comment: Some people also same stomachs 'grumble' or 'gurgle'.  Generally grumble is associated with hunger, as if your stomach is grumbling/complaining about missing a meal.  Gurgle is loosely associated with the sounds your stomach makes when having an upset stomach, although it is used in other cases too.

Comment: @brilliant: yes, "My stomach was rumbling" is perfect.

Comment: @brilliant, if you say your stomach is "rumbling" it might be understood to imply you're about to be sick.

Comment: “Growl” is the only one of those I’ve ever heard in my 65 years as an American.

Comment: @Meg a stomach might **grumble** if it *didn't like* something you ate. The **rumble** is a good answer. The stomach **rumbles** before you eat but might **grumble** about the crumble you ate.

Comment: @ThePhoton I've only ever heard "rumbling" used for hungry noises. For sickness, "churning", "upset", or "queasy" would make more sense.

Comment: To quote Winnie The Pooh: "There's a Rumbly in My Tumbly".

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to say this:

- My stomach is [rumbling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rumble#Verb).

  > #### rumble (verb)
  >
  > 1. To make a low, heavy, continuous sound.
  >
  >    If I don't eat, **my stomach will rumble**.
- My stomach is [grumbling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grumble#Verb).

  > #### grumble (verb)
  >
  > 1. To make a low, **growling** or **rumbling** noise, like a **hungry stomach** or certain animals.
- My stomach is [growling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/growl#Verb).

  > #### growl (verb)
  >
  > 1. To utter a deep guttural sound, as an angry animal; to give forth an angry, **grumbling** sound.
  > 2. (jazz) Of a wind instrument: to produce a low-pitched **rumbling** sound.
- My stomach is [gurgling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gurgle#Etymology).

  > #### gurgle (verb)
  >
  > **Etymology**
  >
  > Back formation from Middle English gurguling "a **rumbling** in the belly".
- My stomach is making noises.